# Abelianization of quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group. Let $N$ $\trianglelefteq$ $G$.

We define $\phi$ : $G$ $\rightarrow$ $G^{ab}$ a homomorphism, where $G^{ab} : = G/[G,G]$ is the abelianization of group $G$.

Is it true that $G^{ab}/\phi(N) \cong (G/N)^{ab}$ and how do we prove it?

Any help or hint is appreciated.

**Edit** : My main idea is to find a homomorphism $f$, then find Ker($f$) and Im($f$).
First, I tried defining $f : G^{ab} \rightarrow G \rightarrow G/N \rightarrow (G/N)^{ab}$. But it seems like the first arrow is not well defined since $\phi^{-1}$ is not guaranteed.
Then I posed $\psi : G^{ab} \rightarrow (G/N)^{ab}$ and wasn’t sure anymore how to continue.

Comment: Try including your thoughts, work that you have tried.

Comment: $G^{\rm ab}/N^{\rm ab}$ need not even make sense. $N^{\rm ab}=N/[N,N]$, $G^{\rm ab}=G/[G,G]$. So $N^{\rm ab}$ is not necessarily a subgroup of $G^{\rm ab}$, since $[N,N]$ need not be equal to $[G,G]$. That is: the very statement you are trying to prove may be nonsensical.

Comment: Also note that $[G,G]\cap N$ contains $[N,N]$, but may be strictly larger. For example, $[S_4,S_4]=A_4$, but if we take $N=\{e,(12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$, then $[N,N]=\{e\}$ but $[S_4,S_4]\cap N=N$.

Comment: I’ve simplified the original statement : $G^{ab}/\phi(N) \simeq (G/N)^{ab}$. I believe it doesn’t make a difference but just to be sure.

Comment: Since $\phi(N)=N[G,G]/[G,G]$, you are now asking whether the abelianization of $G/N$ is isomorphic to $(G/[G,G])/(N[G,G]/[G,G])$, which by the Isomorphism Theorems is isomorphic to $(G/N[G,G])$.

Comment: Simple question : how does $\phi$ send $N$ to $N[G,G]/[G,G]$ ?

Comment: Standard fact: the image of $h\in H$ is $hK$; so the image of $H$ is the collection of all cosets represented by $H$, which is precisely $HK/K$.

Comment: So prove that $G/N[G,G]$ has the "correct" universal property: any morphism from $G/N$ to an abelian group factors uniquely through $G/N[G,G]$.